# Ajax and jQuery call of $ajax url not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I will try to explain it a bit better.

I have REST api I'm connecting to via the URL in the ajax. When I get that information I want to update the content within  so the content is updated according to the data got from the api call.

```
<button onclick="myFunction()">LOAD</button><br /><br />
<div class="spinner bar hide">
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
</div> 
<div class="searchtable"><?php include 'hotels/hotelList.php';?></div>

<script>
    function myFunction() { 
        $('.searchtable').addClass('hide');
        $('.spinner').removeClass('hide');

        $.ajax({
            url: 'hotels/hotelSortBy.php?name=<?php echo $name;?>&arrival=<?php echo $arrival;?>&departure=<?php echo $departure;?>&guests=<?php echo $numberOfGuests;?>'
        }).done(function() {
            $('.spinner').addClass('hide');
            $('.searchtable').removeClass('hide');
        });
    }
</script>
```

Comment: Your question is not clear. Are you saying that you would like the data returned from the AJAX request appended to the `searchtable` elements?

Comment: is this part of generated HTML document? or source of php.file?

Comment: Are you absolutely sure that your file isn't called? You might want to set up your URL in an extra variable and check if before starting the AJAX call.

Comment: I will try to explain it a bit better.

I have REST api I'm connecting to via the URL in the ajax. When I get that information I want to update the content within <div class="searchtable"> so the content is updated according to the data got from the api call.

Comment: you still didn't answer to my question: what is that? is it part of html code? if yest - it is wrong (includes `<?php`) is it php file? if yes - why do you show it to us? show us the html generated by script please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with your ajax call functionality

you have to change your ajax call like below

```
$.ajax({
            type: 'GET',
            data: {'name':'<?php echo $name;?>','arrival':'<?php echo $arrival;?>','departure':'<?php echo $departure;?>','guests':'<?php echo $numberOfGuests;?>'},
            url: 'hotels/hotelSortBy.php',
            success: function (data) {
                // do what ever you want to do with this response data
            },
            error: function (xhr) {
                // do what ever you want to do when error happens
            }
        });
```

Thats the way to send GET request to a url using ajax

Comment: This was finally the correct way for me doing i , and then on succes on recievement of data I replaced data like this `                $('.searchtable').replaceWith(data);
`